# PIVOT Query To Generate The Below Result

Tags: sql-server

```
Input Table
t1  sivaprakash 10  Jan       
t7  Mathi   50  Jan       
t8  Praveen 80  March     
t9  rarna   75  May       
t2  prasanna    70  Feb
t3  Pradeep 30  March     
t4  Mathon  35  April     
t5  Vijaykumar  40  May       
t6  Jeeva   50  June
```

Result:

```
Month                 Jan Feb March April May June July

Number of Transactions 1   2    1    4     1    3    2
```

How can i query for my result?

Comment: at least specify the column names :)

Comment: Why does `Jan` have number of transactions is set to 1?

Comment: Show your own effort first, you are not even providing a good example, just a random result that doesn't make sense with your input

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified anything, but still if you want you can try like following.

```
SELECT 'No Of Transaction' AS Month,* 
FROM   (SELECT 1 AS C1, 
               month 
        FROM   MySampleTable) t 
       PIVOT ( Count(c1) 
             FOR month IN ( [Jan],[Feb],[March],[April],[May],[June]))pvt
```

[**Full Demo**](https://rextester.com/ZIDE81295)

```
+-------------------+-----+-----+-------+-------+-----+------+
| Month             | Jan | Feb | March | April | May | June |
+-------------------+-----+-----+-------+-------+-----+------+
| No Of Transaction | 2   | 1   | 2     | 1     | 2   | 1    |
+-------------------+-----+-----+-------+-------+-----+------+
```